# Nested loops - Looping through open weather API and classes in html

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I am adding a weather element to a web page using OpenWeatherMap API. I have it configured for the appropriate location and has been tested.

I have 5 divs for the 5 day forcast with a h6 for the day name in each (using class name .weather-day). The API provides three objects per day with the relevant date, temp, humidity etc.

I have a *for loop* that will loop through each element with class name .weather-day and set the inner HTML. When I attempt to do a second loop to loop through the weather object, all of the elements end up with the same title.

```js
const link = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + API_KEY;
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', link, true);
request.onload = function() {
  let obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

    // DEFINE DAY DATA

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 15; j += 3) {
        DOMWeatherDay[i].innerHTML = getDayName(obj.list[j].dt);
      }
    }


  } else {
    console.log("The city doesn't exist");
  }
}
request.send();

function getDayName(dt) {
  let date = new Date(dt*1000);
  let days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
  return days[date.getDay()];
}
```

```html
<section class="weather">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h5>Current</h5>
          <p>weather</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p class="current-icon">

          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p class="current-temp">

          </p>
          <p id="current-conditions">

          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6 class="weather-day">Day</h6>
          <p class="weather-icon">
            icon
          </p>
          <p class="weather-hi">
            hi
          </p>
          <p class="weather-lo">
            lo
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6 class="weather-day">Day</h6>
          <p class="weather-icon">
            icon
          </p>
          <p class="weather-hi">
            hi
          </p>
          <p class="weather-lo">
            lo
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6 class="weather-day">Day</h6>
          <p class="weather-icon">
            icon
          </p>
          <p class="weather-hi">
            hi
          </p>
          <p class="weather-lo">
            lo
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6 class="weather-day">Day</h6>
          <p class="weather-icon">
            icon
          </p>[![Example of API object][1]][1]
          <p class="weather-hi">
            hi
          </p>
          <p class="weather-lo">
            lo
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <h6 class="weather-day">Day</h6>
          <p class="weather-icon">
            icon
          </p>
          <p class="weather-hi">
            hi
          </p>
          <p class="weather-lo">
            lo
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

the getDayName function is converting the unix timestamp.

Comment: Can you show us your relevant HTML and a sample of the data that you receive from the OpenWeatherMapAPI so that we can replicate your code? Oh and don't forget the JavaScript where you select your elements.

Comment: I have realised that I am incorrect, there are more than three entries per day. it is every three hours. I will adjust my methods and see how i get on

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content by using `innerHTML` will replace the current contents of that HTML element. You could use `insertAdjacentHTML()` instead, which maintains the contents and allows you to specify where to insert your new markup. [MDN description of insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```
DOMWeatherDay[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getDayName(obj.list[j].dt));
```